# Timestamp changes format when writing to csv file spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a dataframe to a csv file, that contains a timestamp.

The problem that this column changes of format one written in the csv file. Here is the code I used:

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
    
    val df = spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferSchema", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTest2.csv")
    //val df = spark.read.option("header",true).option("inferSchema", "true").csv("C:\\dataSet.csv\\datasetTest.csv")
    //convert all column to numeric value in order to apply aggregation function 
    df.columns.map { c  =>df.withColumn(c, col(c).cast("int")) }
    //add a new column inluding the new timestamp column
    val result2=df.withColumn("new_time",((unix_timestamp(col("time"))/300).cast("long") * 300).cast("timestamp")).drop("time")
    val finalresult=result2.groupBy("new_time").agg(result2.drop("new_time").columns.map((_ -> "mean")).toMap).sort("new_time") //agg(avg(all columns..)
   finalresult.coalesce(1).write.option("header",true).option("inferSchema","true").csv("C:/mydata.csv")
```

when display via df.show it shoes  the correct format[image]

But in the csv file it shoes this format:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use option to format timestamp into desired one which you need:

```
finalresult.coalesce(1).write.option("header",true).option("inferSchema","true").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").csv("C:/mydata.csv")
```

or

```
finalresult.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\t").option("header",true).option("inferSchema","true").option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").option("escape", "\\").save("C:/mydata.csv")
```

Comment: I tried your two option and i got the same problem for the column timestamp

Comment: `dateFormat` option modifies dates; `timestampFormat` modifies timestamps. try the `timestampFormat` option.

Comment: facing same issue, have you found any solution on this ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code snippet that worked for me to modify the CSV output format for timestamps.

I needed a 'T' character in there, and no seconds or microseconds.  The **timestampFormat** option did work for this.

```
DF.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
```

Such as `2017-02-20T06:53`

If you substitute a space for 'T' then you get this:

```
DF.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

Such as `2017-02-20 06:53`